# How to show monthly movement of sales data in python pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a data frame that is grouped by on Month and Car like below :

And want it to be changed to. So that car names is one of the column and I can show monthly sales movement.

So the column names as of now : `Month` , `Car` , `Sales`.

I want it to be changed to `Month` , `Mercedes` , `BMW` with the sales coming in each row.

This is my first question on this site. I have attached screenshot for easy reference. Please advise.

[image: simulation]

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use [**`pd.pivot_table`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html).

```
import pandas as pd
import numpu as np
d = {'Month':['Jun',np.nan,'Jul',np.nan],'Car':['Merc','BMW','Merc','Nissan'],'Sales':[100,200,50,10]}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)

  Month     Car  Sales
0   Jun    Merc    100
1   NaN     BMW    200
2   Jul    Merc     50
3   NaN  Nissan     10
```

Now fill the missing values in `'Month'` using [**`df.fillna`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html)'s `'ffill'` method.

```
df=df.fillna(method='ffill')
df
  Month     Car  Sales
0   Jun    Merc    100
1   Jun     BMW    200
2   Jul    Merc     50
3   Jul  Nissan     10
```

Now pivot table using [**`pd.pivot_table`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html)

```
new_df=pd.pivot_table(df,values='Sales',index='Month',columns='Car',fill_value=0)
Car      BMW   Merc  Nissan
Month
Jul      0.0   50.0    10.0
Jun    200.0  100.0     0.0
```

Now use [**`df.reset_index`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) to get desired output

```
new_df=new_df.reset_index()
new_df

Car Month    BMW   Merc  Nissan
0     Jul    0.0   50.0    10.0
1     Jun  200.0  100.0     0.0
```

`Car` is the axis name to remove `Car` use [**`df.rename_axis`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html)

```
new_df.rename_axis(None,axis=1)

  Month  BMW  Merc  Nissan
0   Jul    0    50      10
1   Jun  200   100       0
```

You can chain all the above step into one line, I wrote in different steps for the sake of better explanation.